# Set the radio button value boolean using angular ionic

Tags: angular, angular-material, ionic4, angular8, mat-table

[image: Radio Button Img]Set the radio button value boolean using angular ionic

> ```
> I want to value of selected radio button in boolean If selected then return true otherwise false return
> ```

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="primary">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                  <mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="row" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" >
                    <mat-radio-button [value]=primary></mat-radio-button>
                  </mat-radio-group>
                </td>
           </ng-container>
```

Comment: Use `checked` property of `mat-radio-button`.

Comment: Can you tell me How to do please make a code and send it

Comment: Could you tell me on what basis you want to select the radio button? any condition ?

Comment: I want to make a primary mobile number(contact detail table) on a checked radio button (On show in table)